# Not able to assign deployed war file to main-server-group in jboss as7

Tags: deployment, jboss

I have jboss in domain mode.
I am not able to assign the deployed war file to the main-server-group. I am able to assign it to other-server-group.

I am getting following error:

```
Failed to add Deployment middleware.war

Unexpected HTTP response: 500
    Request
    {
        "operation" => "composite",
        "address" => [],
        "steps" => [
            {
                "address" => [
                    ("server-group" => "main-server-cgroup"),
                    ("deployment" => "middleware.war")
                ],
                "operation" => "add"
            },
            {
                "address" => [
                    ("server-group" => "main-server-cgroup"),
                    ("deployment" => "middleware.war")
                ],
                "operation" => "deploy"
            }
        ]
    }

    Response

    Internal Server Error
    {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "result" => {
            "step-1" => {"outcome" => "success"},
            "step-2" => {"outcome" => "success"}
        },
        "failure-description" => "JBAS010839: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers.",
        "rolled-back" => true,
        "server-groups" => {"main-server-cgroup" => {"host" => {"master" => {"server-1" => {"response" => {
            "outcome" => "failed",
            "result" => {
                "step-1" => {
                    "outcome" => "failed",
                    "rolled-back" => true
                },
                "step-2" => {
                    "outcome" => "failed",
                    "failure-description" => {
                        "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./middleware" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./middleware: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},
                        "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
                            "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"middleware.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
                            "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.binding.modcluster"]
                        }
                    },
                    "rolled-back" => true
                }
            },
            "failure-description" => {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {
                "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./middleware" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./middleware: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},
                "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
                    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"middleware.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
                    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.binding.modcluster"]
                }
            }}},
            "rolled-back" => true
        }}}}}}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I copied an existing war and didn't change the context-root.

For me, I copied `HelloWorld.war` and created `GetVendors.war` and all I wanted to do was recreate HelloWorld. Unfortunately, I got an error because of the  context-root attribute in `jboss-web.xml`, which should be at the top level of the war.

I just changed

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/HelloWorld</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

to

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/GetVendors</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And it worked.